# Where to install libraries such as hdf5

Tags: install, library

I'm trying to install HDF5 and SZIP following http://www.ulmer.org/2014/building-hdf5-for-os-x-mavericks/[this description].

However, I'm wondering where to install it (on mavericks). Google didn't show anything, is there any space recommended as a destination directory? Please indicate for both current user and all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow those instructions, the package will install everything to `/usr/local`. This is a recommended place to install user-compiled software because it's already in your PATH, doesn't need elevated permissions, and a lot of stuff breaks if it's not in either `/usr` or `/usr/local` . If you open the DEST directory that's created before the pkgutil step, you'll see where everything gets installed. It's the `--PREFIX=/usr/local` in the configure step that decides the path relative to which things get installed.

Incidentally, both those packages can be found in [homebrew](http://brew.sh) which, in my opinion, is a better way to manage these things and you may find more straightforward. After you install homebrew:

```
brew install szip hdf5
```

Comment: I actually ran those lines and it just created everything in my current dir / DEST, which is why I was asking in the first place. home-brew was the solution, thanks.

Comment: So when you run the pkgutil step, it takes the DEST directory and makes a package, which you then have to run to actually install it in the correct location.